# citations for numerical lookup table interpolation of P/ODE(s) RHS

Tags: pde, ode, interpolation

I'm not sure that this *overflow is right place to ask.... Sorry if it is off topic.

Does anyone know a citation (scientific article or book) for a numerical trick (method), when we tabulate a right-hand side of given differential equation(s) and use an interpolation in between rows of the lookup table when we numerically integrate PDEs/ODEs.

This trick speeds up computations but, of course, reduces an accuracy.

The method is well known, but I couldn't find any references in scientific literature.

Also any estimation of how to select correct number of points in lookup table to reach required accuracy of solution will be very helpful.

P.S. I have to clarify the question due to a several answer which aren't answer for my question:

If I have 
$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)$, I can create a lookup table of $y_i=f(x_i)$ for some range of $x_i$. This table is in a memory. I can use interpolation between rows in this table instead of evaluation function  $f(x)\approx y_i+\frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}(x-x_i)$, which is faster than a direct calculation of $f(x)$.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a dirty trick but I assume you are talking about piecewise linear interpolation. If the entries in your table are for equally-spaced values of your independent variable, for a given value of the independent variable you can directly find the appropriate index in the table. How accurate this linear interpolation is depends very much on the specific function you are trying to interpolate.

Comment: @BillGreene Yes, you are absolutely right! But is there any name for this approach? I gave up to find any references for this method. All my books on numerical methods have nothing inside. Any references? Please!

Comment: "piecewise linear interpolation" is the only name I recall seeing. I don't have a particular reference in mind but if I google that phrase there are many hits.

Comment: @BillGreene Unfortunately _"piecewise linear interpolation"_ gives me references for interpolation, but not for usage it to speed up P/ODE calculations... Sorry it doesn't work!

Comment: You won't find references because the literature would assume this is elementary. However, if you mean "higher order interpolations", like the dense output for ODEs, then the reference depends on the integration method.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks, but can you provide any citation for any integration method?

Comment: http://juliadiffeq.org/citing.html quite a few are listed here, including the Dormand-Prince algorithm which is used as ode45. Is that what you're looking for? Most of the original papers for the integration method contain some polynomial interpolation

Comment: Though actually, for the Dormand-Prince interpolation I would cite Hairer's Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I, or one of Shampine's papers (which would be referenced in  that book). What method did you use?

Comment: it seems it is different from what I'm looking for. This interpolation between solutions with different step-size, like RK and so on. All these methods require evaluation of RHS on every iteration. What I'm looking for is different. For ODE x'=f(x) you make a table of **f(x)** vs. **x**, and then you use this lookup table to evaluate RHS when you solve x'=f(x) by any methods.

Comment: Are you just doing a polynomial interpolation using `f(x)` vs `x`? The standard way using the derivative is [Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation), and it's employed by some algorithms as an easy non-fancy way to interpolate (and you can write it for the derivative). I assume you must be using some order Hermite polynomial?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas It is usually a form of linear piecewise interpolation. And it is a standard method to speed up calculations. Many simulators of neural dynamics, such as NEURON or GENESIS, allow to chose if you want evaluate RHS on each simulation step (or even multiple times, depends on used solver) or make a lookup table of RHS  and use linear interpolation instead of RHS evaluation. I need to find any literature / citations.

Comment: Linear interpolation is a sufficiently simple and bad technique that I don't think it requires a citation. How do define a linear interpolation was known likely before modern mathematics. You don't need to cite this. I (and it seems many others) am quite shocked that the software would only give such a basic and inaccurate interpolation...

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas The question isn't in linear interpolation, but substitution of solution of RHS of equation by interpolation (linear or not, doesn't matter). BTW Linear interpolation is not so bad as you think, If you tabulated your activation and inactivation functions with small step you can get very nice precision by doing just something like this table[(int)((x-x0)/step)].... you get 3 CPU operations instead of thousands to resolve couple exponential functions and quite a lot of arithmetic.....

Comment: But the other interpolations are designed to also be just as cheap (not requiring function evaluations), but match the order of the algorithm. Using a linear interpolation, your algorithm is now only first order. If you're only using it in a pinch that should be fine, but that would lead to some big errors if you're doing something like event handling.

Comment: I'm doubt that you can decide which is the algorithm's order using just order of interpolation. Imagine that you do standard RK4, so you need 4 time get f(x), right? But who tell you that you will have all 4 time from the same piece of piecewise interpolation?! If table made with small enough step, accuracy of the linear interpolation may be much higher than accuracy of your numerical method! Table will be huge, and won't fit into cache, so this trick won't speed computation up much, but still.....

Comment: "I'm doubt that you can decide which is the algorithm's order using just order of interpolation". Just do the proof. It's quite trivial to see that if your `f` is only first order, none of your other approximations can do better than first order. Generally, your computations are only as good as your worst approximation. There are exceptions like boundary conditions on PDEs can in some cases be 1 order less, but those are exceptions and not the norm.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that it is a trick (interpolation is one of the most basic numerical techniques) and I don't see why it would be "dirty" (though it may be inaccurate).  I don't think there is a special name attached to interpolation between solutions of a differential equation.

Comment: I need a citation to use it in my paper. I couldn't find any scientific source (article or book), which can be cited. This technique is well known, but have anyone described it in scientific literature?

Comment: If you didn't learn about it by reading a paper, I don't think you *need* a citation to use it in your paper.

Comment: I'm a scientist. I learned about this method from code, but it is really weird that numerical methods guys did not study this **method** in details. I couldn't believe, it must be in each textbook with estimations of O() and so on. And it is very risky to use method which wasn't properly studied.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, the name I have always known for this kind of tabular integration is "numerical quadrature".  In the days of calculating machines this was the only way of going about solving differential equations.  It was important to minimise the number of points at which you have to calculate the right hand side of $y' = f(x)$.

One very effective method of achieving this was referred to as "*Richardson's deferred approach to the limit*" in which you can choose two different step sizes, $h_1$ and $h_2$, to define points at which you evaluate $f(x)$.  If using these two step sizes results in estimates $f_1$ and $f_2$ for the value at a specific point, you can combine these to produce an answer which is better than if you had picked a finer resolution.

Famously, if $h_1 = 2 h_2$, then $f = f_2 + (f_2 - f_1)/3$ is $O(h^3)$.

In effect, a "free lunch". If the accuracy was still not good enough, you would choose a smaller $h_3$, and so on.  There were many papers on the choice of sequence $\{h_i\}$.  The method was also adapted for extrapolation and for summing slowly convergent series.

This was first discussed by Richardson and Gaunt, 1926, *Phil. Trans. A*, **226**, 299-361.  When solving ODE's we refer to this as Richardson Extrapolation, see Press et al. *Numerical Recipes* Section 16.4 et. seq. in the context of the important Bulirsch-Stoer method for solving ODE's.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts and answer. I really apologize, for unclear question (see P.S. to my post). I believe word interpolation triggers incorrect interpretation of my question. I didn't mean interpolation between several step sizes, I mean interpolation instead of evaluation ofr RHS of equation.

Comment: @rth: It's clear now, thanks.  A remark about accuracy: your linear evaluation of f(x) at the required value x requires values at a point either side of x: x(i) and x(i+1) and the corresponding f(i) and f(i+1).  If you use two points either side, x(i-1), x(i), x(i+1), x(i+2) (but not necessarily equally spaced) you can use the Richardson-Aitken trick to improve the accuracy at f(x).  It's quicker and computationally far cheaper than using local orthogonal polynomial fits, but obviously not as accurate as some other methods involving a greater number of function evaluations.